# More activities or 1-2 activities and multiple fragments? Jetpack compose or XML or both?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm building a simple app that's basically text input and multiple-choice input from a recycler view, pulled from an api. Then exporting the form answers to a pdf, uploading that to a database and accessing the database.

That being said, I've only worked with XML and with multiple activities but not with fragments. So, my questions re:
Is there a rule of thumb for when to use activity vs when to use a fragment?
Should I continue with XML since I'm doing basic things here or is it worth learning jetpack compose since I am on a deadline?

Comment: First off, you're asking several unrelated questions here.  Secondly, each of them is an opinion question, which is off topic here.  There's ways to ask about the pros and cons of say activities vs fragments (which btw aren't the only two options), but the way you're asking is far too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a rule of thumb for when to use activity vs when to use a fragment?

The fragments were created to make supporting different screen sizes easier, so if you are planning on making apps that do support all screen sizes, you would use fragments

Example: gmail on a phone and a tablet:

[image][image]

As you see on the tablet there are more componenets visible, which were (probably) created with fragments

> Should I continue with XML since I'm doing basic things here or is it worth learning jetpack compose since I am on a deadline?

As a person that had to switch to compose due to work related reasons, I would recommend sticking to XML, making a smooth working app with low experience in compose will be a bit tricky (it took me more than a month to get used to compose)

Comment: Also it has become a bit of a community-standard to use `one activity, multiple fragments` approach in your android apps, but that doesn't really matter

Comment: It's a common way of doing things, but far from universal.  Lots of apps still use activities.  Lots of apps also choose neither of those, since fragments are pretty universally considered clunky in large apps (try putting a fragment in a recycler view and you'll see why the fragment API is pretty horrible).

Comment: "Lots of apps still use activities." mostly applications created in the past I think, also that example is.... not the best (with all due respects), why would one want to create a fragment for each item in recycler view?

Comment: No, lots of new applications do too.  Most places I've worked over the last decade have banned fragments because the API for them is too problematic.  They use the same type of idea of reusable UI pieces, but they roll their own.  And as for the recyclerview-  a fragment is a set of UI and functionality that you want to reuse in multiple places.  One of those can easily be a recycler view.  In fact it's one of the most common ones. The inability to do so is one of the reasons why Fragments are considered a failed idea.

Comment: Good to learn something new, I am but a junior dev :D